# getting different parts in a list while skipping some objects

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, element

So I have created a list consisting of dates and numbers that I got from a text file which includes some lotto numbers. I am trying to access certain parts in the list, to create multiple lists of the different numbers available as I would later like to do some statistical work on the numbers ie how many times a number appears in the different lists etc. Thus showing numbers according to popularity.

I am still new to python and thought that this would really be a good project to get started in testing what I know so far and to continue on working as I get better with python.

My list below consists of the following: 'Day', 'Month', 'year', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5' repeat for a number of days

['03', 'March', '2020', '33', '16', '18', '10', '04', '02', 'March', '2020', '14', '13', '34', '04', '20', '01', 'March', '2020', '10', '08', '15', '02', '23', '29', 'February', '2020', '16', '28', '20', '07', '35', '28', 'February', '2020', '31', '35', '10', '30', '29', '27', 'February', '2020', '25', '26', '05', '03', '19', '26', 'February', '2020', '33', '21', '29', '11', '32', '25', 'February', '2020', '10', '19', '13', '05', '08', '24', 'February', '2020', '14', '29', '33', '31', '09', '23', 'February', '2020', '04', '27', '05', '11', '12', '22', 'February', '2020', '18', '05', '27', '34', '20', '21', 'February', '2020', '29', '10', '15', '25', '12', '20', 'February', '2020', '33', '03', '12', '27', '05', '19', 'February', '2020', '06', '14', '26', '04', '29', '18', 'February', '2020', '07', '08', '23', '32', '30', '17', 'February', '2020', '05', '32', '22', '21', '19', '16']

Here is the code I have used thus far, which will take forever to do what I want to do considering I would like to increase the information to provide better statistics.

```
#read txt file and convert info into list
    with open('results.txt') as f:
    line = f.read()
    a = line.split()

#Skipping the day-month-year to only return the numbers

list_1 = a[3:9]
list_2 = a[11:17]

print(a)
print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I would like to learn more and understand where I might improve my idea and make life easier. Maybe it is a bit difficult project to start with but i'm thinking long term here in where I am going with it... Lol

Comment: how do you want your output to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to put it neatly into a list of lists.

`range` takes 3 arguments. the start point, the stop point, and the amount you wish to step by. Stepping to the position of every date, you can just slice the section of the list you want out.

```
import pprint
all_numbers = []

for i in range(0, len(a), 8):
    if len(a[i + 3:i + 8]):
        all_numbers.append(a[i + 3:i + 8])

pprint.pprint(all_numbers)
```